# Redirect query string URL via .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am trying to redirect all query strings to a new URL.

Search query example `www.example.com/?s=cars` to resolve to `www.example.com/?search_gcse/?q=cars` ("cars" is just an example).

What is the syntax for the .htaccess rule?

Answer (score 3):

Partly depends on which question mark you want to keep. You have two question marks in the URL that you're trying to resolve to & that won't work. I'll assume that the last question mark is the one you want to keep

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:&|^)s=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/search_gcse/?q=%1 [R=302,L]
```